# Weird line appearing in BarLegend

Tags: plotting, legending

My BarLegend has a weird line appearing in it. Why??

```
BarLegend[{GrayLevel, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing my code, I realised that setting `Mesh` options for `ArrayPlot` can affect `BarLegend` in unforeseen ways. The code below produces the "weird" line:

```
SetOptions[ArrayPlot, Mesh -> {All, None}];
BarLegend[{GrayLevel, {0, 1}}]
```

Whereas removing the `Mesh` fixes the problem.

```
SetOptions[ArrayPlot, Mesh -> None];
BarLegend[{GrayLevel, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]